# Deploy a vs10 website on a windows server 2003 - IIS 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a client project in which i can run it on my visual studio, and see my .aspx pages. But when i try putting it on my client server,
i aways get HTTP 404.
- I know on IIS 6 i have to manually add the .dll and i've done this process:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/

but it didnt worked.
If any info needed just ask, i'm online 24/7
thanks for the help

Comment: Which version of .net is the app pool running and is set to integrated or classic?

Comment: The server runs in .net 2, and i dont know if is integrated or classic

Comment: mvc versions 1 and 2 require at least version 3.5 of .NET and mvc version 3 requires .NET 4.0. You might be able to get mvc to run under 2.0 with tweaks, however, I would suggest you upgrade you server and set you application to run under an app pool configured with the officially supported version of .NET

Comment: just to be assured, the .net version you were talking, was this : http://prntscr.com/f0rfhv ?

Comment: Yes, are there any other versions available in that drop down list?

Comment: I really wish i could upgrade, but this is not mine server, and my client has some business running on it, that's the reason i needed to try at least

Comment: And no, it is the only version

Comment: Are you sure it is an MVC app? You mention .aspx, are yo sure it is not a standard webforms application?

Comment: I asked my boss this same question, he answered this to me : "if it is running on visual studio, then we can run on his server"

Comment: Ok, you stated MVC earlier which can not run under 2.x. I think you are actually running a web forms application. I would update your question once you validate the application type because that matters a lot. If it is a standard web app then there is a checklist of things to try. For one, do you have the correct mime type configured in iis for .aspx under you application and is your application running as a web application, not a web site?

Comment: he said it is mvc, i'll try installing .net 3.5

Comment: just to clarify, you said if it was a web app, we could try a few things, what would be them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are deploying a traditional webforms(.aspx) application, your version of .NET should be fine.

You can refer to online resources such as this [checklist of deploying to IIS](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/32210/deployment-of-a-website-on-iis) for more guidance.